# Resource for replacing a file

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-solo, cookbook

Hi I am looking for a chef resource which can help to replace a file. For example I have a war file for 1.2 version and I want to delete this war file and want to place 2.0 version war file. is there any resource in chef to do this work. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you are getting the WAR file, probably what you want is a `remote_file` resource, or possibly a custom resource that can talk to Artifactory or similar.

Comment: My scenario is like how can I delete the old war file and add new one in one resource or using multiple resource @coderanger

Comment: Resources are descriptions of desired state, so if you tell it you want new content in the file, Chef takes care of the rest.